# Launching instrumented tests on REAL DEVICE produces timed out waiting for process to appear - MacBook Air M1

Tags: android, android-studio, timeout, apple-m1, instrumented-test

I'm stuck on a time out error, and after reading about all the subjects on Stack Overflow I can't find a solution for my problem.

I'm trying to launch an instrumented test from Android Studio (last version) on a real device (I tried different devices, it doesn't seem to be related to the device)

The test I'm trying to launch has been automatically generated by Espresso Test Recorder.
Only the tests produce time out, I can launch the app normally.

I'm working on a MacBook Air M1, on last version of Android Studio if it makes a difference. But since I'm trying to run the test on a real device, it shouldn't be a problem... right? Are there here some people who encountered this kind of problem?

Already tried to plug/unplug the phone, invalidate cache/ restart ; can't try to launch on an emulator since I'm on a M1 Mac...

Comment: Make sure you have no other instance of Android studio open

Comment: I'm sure of it.

Comment: Did you disable animation on that device from the developer tools in the Device Settings ?